# How to prevent duplication in usage message for Information and Double Usage Line within DocumentationTools

Tags: documentation, usage-messages

- In `DocumentationTools` palette within Wolfram Workbench there a
  `Double Usage Line` which is used to write usage description in the
  documentation.
- The usage message for `Information` function is however created by
  `symbol::usage="..."` outside of `Private` context but within package
  context.

The two are the kept the same for all functions by convention. I want to follow this for my package as well. But I have to write the usage message and the documentation message separately. Is there a convenient way I can link the usage message to the documentation so if I need to update anything, I just do it in the documentation and the usage message updates in the other place.